# Why Managed instance is taking more time to create?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-managed-instance

why managed instance taking more time to create?

It has been almost two days managed instance creation started and it is still showing deployment under progress. This is the first time I'm creating MI. Does anyone know how long will it take to create?

Very basic specification: Gen4 8 core 256 memory location: south central us

I don't see any error yet.

Answer (score 2):

Creating first instance within a subnet takes few hours as Managed Instance is customer VNet-injected service and it takes time to provision the whole dedicated cluster - it's much more work than taking random pre-provisioned VM and spinning up few processes on it.
That said, anything that takes more than 6 hours (at the moment, subject of improvement) indicates some sort of issue.
I'd suggest opening support ticket, or you can contact me via private message with more details for the specific instance.

Comment: Thanks. I've created a support ticket.

Comment: The issue has been resolved after including MS software engineers from overseas. The issue was an effective route on vnet. Solution: MS network engineers suggest to switch to using ExpressRoute Private peering

Answer (score 1):

Two days is excessive, and likely indicates a bug in Azure's back-end scripts. When provisioning large amounts of objects in your Azure subscription, you can run out of resources within your 'Ring', which is a pre-allocated set of resources you have to work with. In the event you've exhausted these resources, it does take some time for Azure to provision more before the managed instance can be created.

I've deployed 10 or so Managed Instances and have seen deployment time take anywhere from 
1 to 8 hours for a healthy deploy, and over a day for a deploy that ran into a bug.